# NSTask failed 22 terminating temporary process cocoa

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

Using below code, I am getting this error:

```
NSTask: Task create for path '/Users/media/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Manager-gnixeptcszdoubbnfcncumzypwge/Build/Products/Debug/lib' failed: 22, "Invalid argument".  Terminating temporary process.
```

I am not getting whats the issue behind this.

```
- (void)startProcessingVideo {

     NSLog(@"Processing Video Low Resolution");

    NSTimeInterval timeStamp = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
    // NSTimeInterval is defined as double
    NSNumber *timeStampObj = [NSNumber numberWithInt:timeStamp];

    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterNoStyle];

    NSString *convertNumber = [formatter stringForObjectValue:timeStampObj];

    NSLog(@"timeStampObj:: %@", convertNumber);

    NSString *fileNameNumber = [convertNumber stringByAppendingString:[self genRandStringLength:8]];

    NSLog(@"fileNameNumber:::: %@", fileNameNumber);

    NSString *aString = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", thumbnailDirPath,@"/Mobile" ,fileNameNumber] retain];

    //NSString *string = [aString stringByAppendingString:@"_H"];

    fileNameMP4Mobile = [aString stringByAppendingString:@".mp4"];

    NSLog(@"string:::: %@", aString);

    [lblMessage setStringValue:@"Started!"];
    NSTask *task= [NSTask new];
    [task setLaunchPath:ffmpegPresetLaunchPath];
    [task setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                        @"-y",
                        @"-i",
                        inputFilePath,// @"1.wmv",
                        @"-vcodec",
                        @"libx264",
                        @"-fpre",
                        @"libx264-fast.ffpreset",
                        @"-b",
                        @"500k",
                        @"-s",
                        @"640*480",
                        @"-r",
                        @"30",
                        @"-aspect",
                        @"16:9",
                        @"-ab",
                        @"128k",
                        @"-ac",
                        @"2",
                        @"-ar",
                        @"44100",
                        fileNameMP4Mobile,nil]];
    [task setCurrentDirectoryPath:thumbnailDirPath];

    NSPipe *outputPipe = [NSPipe pipe];
    [task setStandardInput:[NSPipe pipe]];
    [task setStandardOutput:outputPipe];

    [task launch];
    [task waitUntilExit];
    [task release];

    NSData *outputData = [[outputPipe fileHandleForReading] readDataToEndOfFile];
    NSString *outputString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:outputData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
    [lblMessage setStringValue:@"Video Generated!"];

    [self startProcessingVideoHighResolution];
}
```

value for ffmpegPresetLaunchPath is:

```
ffmpegPresetLaunchPath = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", currentDir, @"/lib/"] retain];
```

Value in NSLOG:

```
ffmpegPresetLaunchPath::: /Users/media/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FileManager-gnixeptcszdoubbnfcncumzypwge/Build/Products/Debug/lib/
```

Please help resolving this issue.

Comment: Please show the value of `ffmpegPresetLaunchPath`; it's almost certainly causing the error.

Comment: Please check, I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not providing the correct **file** to execute; you are passing its path (presumably).

You probably need something like:

```
ffmpegPresetLaunchPath = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", currentDir, @"/lib/ffmpeg"] retain];
```

Note: It's clear than [error 22](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/intro.2.html) is the `errno` value `EINVAL`, however there is no reference to it on the `exec()` [manpage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/exec.3.html) or `execve()` [manpage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/execve.2.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/2/execve)., so I don't know how you're expected to determine the cause from just the error code.